# Please help! What am I missing with my form?

Tags: php, forms, post, submit

I'm working with a form that I've altered from another site I created, which works, and for some reason it's not working here. I've been through the code a hundred times and am missing the vital clue!

The form includes php validation. If the required fields aren't filled it shows the form again, with anything that HAS been filled automatically put into the new form. Except that     it's not automatically filling those completed fields, and it's not validating a valid submission.

I'm guessing that the data isn't being posted correctly, but I can't see where the problem is!

Here's the initial form:

```
<form name="userform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
<table>
  <tr>
<td class="form_item_name">Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="form_item_name">Company name:</td><td><input type="text" name="company">    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="form_item_name">Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="form_item_name">Phone:</td><td><input type="text" name="phone"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="form_item_name"></td>
<td>
<select name="subject">
<option value="Requesting A Quote" selected="selected">Requesting A Quote</option>
<option value="Product/Service Support">Product/Service Support</option>
<option value="General Enquiry">General Enquiry</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="form_item_name">Your comments:</td><td><textarea style="resize:none; width:350px;" name="comments" rows="10" wrap="hard"></textarea><br />
<br />
<input class="button_send" type="image" value=" " src="images/transparent.gif"></form>
```

And here's the action php (send_form_email.php):

```
<?php
if(strlen($name) > 2 &&
strlen($email) > 2 &&
strlen($comments) > 2) {

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_to = "sales@happytobevisuals.com";
$email_from = "Website: Contact Us";

if (strpos($subject,'General Enquiry') !== false) {
$email_subject = "General Enquiry";
}
elseif (strpos($subject,'Product/Service Support') !== false) {
$email_subject = "Product/Service Support";
}
elseif (strpos($subject,'Request A Quote') !== false) {
$email_subject = "Quote Request";
}
$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Company: ".clean_string($company)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
$email_message .= "Phone: ".clean_string($phone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

"Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message);
?>
<font face="times new roman" color="#FFF" size="+3">Thanks for that, your message has been sent!</font><br>
<a href="http://www.happytobevisuals.co.nz" class="nav_ingredients">Click here to go back to the home page</a>

<?php
}else{
?>
<font face="times new roman" color="#FFF" size="+3">Woops! Missed something ...</font>
<br>
<br>

<form name="userform" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();" action="send_form_email.php">
<table>
  <tr>
<td class="form_item_name">Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="form_item_name">Company name:</td><td><input type="text" name="company" value="<?php echo $company;?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="form_item_name">Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="form_item_name">Phone:</td><td><input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone;?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="form_item_name"></td>
<td>
//this next bit's about autofilling the dropdown to reflect their previous selection
<?php
if (strpos($subject,'General Enquiry') !== false) {
echo '<select name="subject">
<option value="General Enquiry">General Enquiry</option>
<option value="Product/Service Support">Product/Service Support</option>
<option value="Complaint">Complaint</option>
</select>';
}
if (strpos($subject,'Product/Service Support') !== false) {
echo '<select name="subject">
<option value="General Enquiry">General Enquiry</option>
<option value="Product/Service Support" selected="selected">Product/Service Support</option>
<option value="Complaint">Complaint</option>
</select>';
}
if (strpos($subject,'Complaint') !== false) {
echo '<select name="subject">
<option value="General Enquiry">General Enquiry</option>
<option value="Product/Service Support">Product/Service Support</option>
<option value="Complaint" selected="selected">Complaint</option>
</select>';
}
}
?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="form_item_name">Your comments:</td><td><textarea style="resize:none; width:350px;" name="comments" rows="10" wrap="hard"><?php echo $comments ?></textarea><br />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="valid"></form>
```

So... can you see it? All help appreciated!

PS. Is there a quicker way on stackoverflow to put code into a block than adding four spaces manually before each line? Cheers :)

Comment: You can select your code and click the '{}' icon for formatting code.

Comment: Yes, there's a quicker way to put all your code into a block, at the click of a button. Simply select all your code & click the {} button on the Editor. That will wrap up the selected chunk of text into code format & you would not have to do it manually.

Comment: While you're at it, make sure you encode the variables properly, like this `value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($company) ?>"`

Comment: Dave M and Devner: Thanks for that! That'll make it much easier :)

Mark Eirich: I've changed that, thanks for the tip - is that more stable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see where $name, $email, etc are coming from. Did you assinged the $_POST data to your variables?
this way

```
$name = $_POST['name'] 
$email = $_POST['email'] 
$phone = $_POST['phone'] 
$comments = $_POST['comments']

//etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have register_globals off on this host (which is a VERY good thing from a security standpoint - see http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php !), which explains why this was working on your other host but not here.  If that's the case, the variables you're referencing don't exist in the global scope.  Use the $_POST array when referencing posted variables.

This at the top of your script should get it working:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
// etc...
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it's working now! And I'm glad I've got it explained why it's working one and not the other ... could've been very confusing :) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull the variables from the $_POST array in order to utilize them in PHP. Your HTML is fine, but to retrieve the form submission, you must use code akin to the following:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
```